# How to extract a variable from JSON object in php?

Tags: php, json

I am working on a website in which I want to extract JSON variable in php. The code which I have used for that is:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="policies">
   <p> 
      <span class="heading_size">policies:</span>

   </p>
   <p class="text-justify mb-0 pb-5">
      <?php 
         echo strtolower($data['item']->company_policy->description); 
         ?>
   </p>
</div>
```

In the above code the following line  `echo strtolower($data['item']->company_policy->description);` doesn't seems to print anything  but for the debugging purpose when I have added `<?php echo $data['item']; ?>`, it is extracting the following snippets of JSON:

```
"company_policy": {
    "company_policy_id": 2,
    "uuid": "B4d2aa790",
    "name": "Reasonable",
    "description": "a.) Hello World. ",
    "cutoff_time": 96,
    "percentage": "1.00"
},
```

In order to extract the **description** from the above JSON, it is understood that I should be using             `echo strtolower($data['item']->company_policy->description);` but it doesn't seems to extract anything as explained above.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the above `echo statement` so that I am successfully able to fetch the data from the JSON.

Comment: `json_decode($data['item'], true)`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh What should I be writing here ? `echo strtolower($data['item']->company_policy->description);`

Comment: @flash A JSON formatted string, as far as PHP is concerned, is just a string. As said before, you need to use `json_decode()`. When debugging your code, always make sure you [turn on error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) or check the error log file. You likely would have received some sort of error when doing this because you are attempting to treat a string like an object.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the answer. Can you let me know what exactly I have to use ?

Comment: @Mike like in place of this echo `strtolower($data['item']->company_policy->description);` what I should be using ?

Comment: Did you read the link in Paul Crovella's comment above?

Comment: yes I read his comment.

Comment: @flash Did you click on the link in his comment, go to the other page, and read the first answer there? That's pretty in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have decode json data by using json_decode

```
<?php $jsonData =  json_decode($data['item'], true); ?>

<div class="tab-pane" id="policies">
   <p> 
      <span class="heading_size">policies:</span>

   </p>
   <p class="text-justify mb-0 pb-5">
      <?php 
         echo strtolower($jsonData['company_policy']['description']); 
         ?>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, it worked. Thanks for the help. I am wondering, why its not working in my way ? I am very curious regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you need to specify if you want an associative array instead of an object from json_decode, this would be the code:
json_decode($jsondata, true);